# Excel: Output as a range with matching dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible with the `IF` formula to `get` Excel to give an output of a range where the values match a date in a column?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `=RANGE()` function in Excel

Comment: If i do this
=IF(C2:C131104=X3;range();"")
Then i get an error in output.

What am i doing wrong ?